# Spring Boot MongoRepository Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, repository, mongorepository

I'm a little new to spring and I've been running into a Null Pointer Exception.
I believe the `@Autowired` is not working on my MongoRepository.
For some reason when I tried some examples it was working. (The commented out code in the run function worked)

This is the error I get:

> 2016-05-20 02:31:20.877 ERROR 6272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.applesauce.service.CustomerService.addCustomer(CustomerService.java:24)
>   ~[classes/:na]

Can you guys take a look and direct me?
Also, please let me know if i'm doing something wrong for best practices.
If you need anymore information, please ask!

com.applesauce.controller

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

private CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();

@RequestMapping(value = "/addcustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Customer addCustomer(@RequestParam("firstName") String fName,
                         @RequestParam("lastName") String lName,
                         @RequestParam("email") String email,
                         @RequestParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,
                         @RequestParam("source") String source){
    return customerService.addCustomer(new Customer(fName,lName,email,phoneNumber,source));
}
}
```

com.applesauce.repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

com.applesauce.service

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.applesauce.repository")
public class CustomerService {

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository repository;

public Customer addCustomer(Customer customer){

    repository.save(customer);

    return customer;
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't your `CustomerService` intended to be a Spring `@Service`? Annotate as it instead and don't create it manually, use `@Autowired`. By the way, you should remove all the non-related code from your question, that also includes all the lines being commented.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed some of the code.  Can you explain "Annotate as it instead and don't create it manually, use @Autowired." this part a little more? I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xtreme Biker meant, that you should add @Service annotation for your CustomerService, like this:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.applesauce.repository")
@Service
public class CustomerService {
...
}
```

Also, you never want to create service using new operator, if you expect Spring to take care about it. In your CustomerController, change initialization line:

```
private CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
```

to:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;
```

It must solve NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Check you would have created an object of the class which has a @Service annotation (using new). This class should also be autowired instead, where you have autowired your repository bean.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved this way (explanation is generic)

Repository.class

```
@Repository
public interface {...}
```

Service.class

```
public class {...}
@Autowired 
private Repository repo;
```

Application.class

```
@Autowired Service service;
service.method() //does not throws NullPointerException
```